# Apache Tika performance impact due to Tesseract

Tags: performance, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

We are using Tika 2.4.0 and we scan hundreds of file to extract content from file, we have combination of file like pdfs, documents (docx) and plain text(.txt) files.

pdfs and docx can have only text or both text and images or only images.

Since we are using ocr to extract content from images, we observe that it is having more resource consumption in terms of memory and cpu(although this is expected behavior). But due to this we see processing of other files is also impacted due to choking of resources.

Is there a way we can have tesseract to run in different machine and give call to it on need basis. Little skeptical on this point as we provide tesseract path in tika config and its not service call.

Or any other solution recommended, to overcome such performance impact, so that when one file is under OCR'ing other files are still processed.

Comment: How are you using Apache Tika - Server on Docker, Server running locally, Java API?

Comment: we are using docker. I mean Apache tika independently running as container. From our application we give rest call to apache tika application running in container.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I've got exactly same problem